# Want to use regular expression in Python to group words the way character classes and repetition quantifiers group characters

Tags: python, regex, text-processing

I have a problem I am trying to solve in python, using re.  I can use regex if I need the extended features, but my needs seem to be simple.

I have the following text for example:

```
one
one two 
one two three
one two three four
one two three four five
```

I want to get back the lines with 1, 2, or 3 words on them, bypassing the rest, so in the above example text, the first 3 lines will match, and the others will not.

The text is generated by the tesseract ocr utility, so the text can be just about anything, garbled mistakes and all, so I am finding words using \S in a character class like this: `[\S]+`

I have the following regular expression that works:

```
^[\S]+[ ]?[\S]+?[ ]?[\S]+?[ ]?$
```

The problem is, I am in the prototype phase of development, and I'm guessing I will need to expand this to accept up to six words, and at the same time, skip lines with only one word.

The regex could easily be expanded to do this, but I am almost certain I will end up needing a regex to capture up to three lines in a row that meet my single-line criteria.

So, thanks to [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info), I am learning more about regular expressions, and see how character classes -- [] and repetition quantifiers -- {} work.

**What I want is a way to use character classes and repetition quantifiers to group words instead of characters.**

I know I could to this all line-by-line in python, but using a regular expression will allow me to expand my solution as I encounter more ocr output in the tool I am building.

Any help on how to proceed?

---- Adding test code and pythex.org screenshot detailing differing behavior.

Wiktor's regex is ^\S+(?: \S+){0,2}$

Test code:

```
import re


def testre(pattern, text):
    p = re.compile(pattern, re.M)
    results = p.findall(text)
    print(f'Test Results: {results}')


txt = 'one\none two\none two three\none two three four\none two three four five\n'
pattern1 = r'^\S+(?: \S+){0,2}$'
print(f'Test string...\n{txt}')
print(f'Test regex: {pattern1}')
testre(pattern1, txt)
```

Runtime shows that Wiktor's expression works as expected:

```
Test string...
one
one two
one two three
one two three four
one two three four five

Test regex: ^\S+(?: \S+){0,2}$
Test Results: ['one', 'one two', 'one two three']
```

However, running this on pythex.org shows 'one two' not matching:
[image]

Wiktor's regex works, but the different result seen on pythex.org is a little concerning.  I hope to use pythex for testing purposes.

Comment: Your pattern must look like `^\S+(?: \S+){0,2}$` and you may customize it further by changing `2` to the `n-1` times value.

Comment: Wiktor, I believe you have got it.  Your answer gives slightly different results when I try it out on pythex.org, compared to when I use it in my code, but that is a question for another day.  If you post this as the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Could you please post the code and explain what does not work? I think that would add value to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things you should know about the `^[\S]+[ ]?[\S]+?[ ]?[\S]+?[ ]?$` pattern: 1) it won't match 1- or 2-char "words" becuse `\S+`, `[\S]+?` and `[\S]+?` here each require at least one non-whitespace chars, 2) you should not (over|ab)use character classes, `[\S]` = `\S`, but `[\b]` != `\b` and `[.]` != `.`. Only use character classes when necessary to avoid messing up the pattern.

You can use

```py
^\S+(?: \S+){0,2}$          # One to three "word" string with a regular space between the words only
^\S+(?:\s\S+){0,2}$         # One to three "word" string with any whitespace between the words only
^\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,2}$        # One to three "word" string with one or more whitespace chars between the words only
^\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,2}\s*$  # One to three "word" string with one or more whitespace chars between
                            #  the words and allowing leading/trailing whitespace in the string
```

**NOTE**: `\S+` matches any 1+ non-whitespace chars, and it can match `abc`, `abc123,`, `---++===`, etc. If you mean to match words (letters, digits, `_`), you may use `\w+`. If you want to only match letter words, use `[^\W\d_]+`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - zero or more any whitespace chars
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `(?:\s+\S+){0,2}` - zero to two occurrences of one or more any whitespace chars and then one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s*` - zero or more any whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I knew my initial regex was not too useful.  I was using [\S+] for word capture because I have seen noise in my tesseract OCR output due to sketchy scans, and wanted to at least make sure I captured everything for evaluation, with the intent of either rescanning noisy pages, or hand-editing results if the noise is low enough.

Comment: @user1945982 In your string, after `one two`, there is a space. You need a `^\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,2}\s*$` or `^ *\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,2} *$` to also match leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: Upvoted answer, as it was very helpful.  Putting the space in my test string made the output match the pythex example.  However, your two alternates consumed the first line and the second line in one match: Test Results: ['one\none two ', 'one two three'].  I will move forward with your examples and make them handle my OCR output.  Thanks again Wiktor.

Comment: @user1945982 If you need to make sure the matches cannot span across lines, simply use the first regex with a regular space, `^ *\S+(?: \S+){0,2} *$`, or `^[^\S\r\n]*\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]\S+){0,2}[^\S\r\n]*$`. It is due to `\s` that matches any kind of whitespace, even line break chars.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor -- I realized the \s was making it span lines, and corrected it. My final goal with this regular expression is to allow it to span a limited number of lines, the same way it spans a limited number of words  For anyone later who wants a regex to capture 1-3 line groups like that, this is working for me: (?:^[\s]*\S+(?: +\S+){0,2}[\s]*\n){1,3}

Comment: @user1945982 Note  that you require a line feed at the end of the 3rd line, so it might be necessary to pass `contents + "\n"` to the regex engine if there is none.